# Resetting redux state without breaking react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

Been working with redux in a complex react application.
I put some data in redux state and use this data to render a component.
Then, you want to change the page and I do need to reset some fields in the redux state. Those fields were used to render the previous component.
So, if I reset the state before going to the next page, the previous page rerenders and throws errors because data is missing (because of the reset). But I can't reset in the next page, because that page is reached in many flows so it can be difficult to manage when to reset and when not.

How problems like this are managed in react applications?
All the example are simplified to show the problem. in the actual application, there are many fields to reset.

so, page 1
redux state

```
{field: someValue}
```

component uses the field value

```
function myComponent(props) => {
  return (props.field.someMappingOperation());
}
```

Now, when going to page 2, field should be null, so we reset it
redux state

```
{field: null}
```

the component above rerenders, throwing an error because of

```
   props.field.someMappingOperation()
```

and field is null.
What can be done is to load the next page, so this component is not in the page and then reset the state. yet, this becomes very hard to manage, because you the are in page B (suppose clients list with the list saved in redux) and you want to see the details of a client you go to page C, when you press back you don't want to reset again the state. So you add conditions on the reset. But because there are many flows in the application, that page can be reached in many ways. Have conditions for each way is not the best solution I suppose.

Edit:
I would like to add that state reset was not required initially and components aren't designed for that. As the application grew and became enough complex it became necessary. I'm looking for a solution that does not require me to add props value checking in every and each component, like

```
{this.props.field && <ComponentThatUsesField />}
```

This is really a lot of work and it's bug-prone as I may miss some fields.

As the application has a lot of pages and manages a lot of different data, the store results to be big enough to not want to have clones of it.

Comment: Are you asking how to handle `null` value of your props? Cause to me, a `null` or even `undefined` value is a valid state. If the state you have is not related to the state in another component, then you are barking up the wrong state tree I would say, how many stores do you have behind all of this?

Comment: use separate `field` - 'namespaced' - multiple counter instance problem in redux

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your components in a more resilient way so they don't crash if their inputs are empty.

For example:

```
render() {
  return (
    { this.props.field && <ComponentUsingField field={this.props.field} />}
  )
}
```

That's a dummy example, but you get the point.

Comment: But, is that the question? When the OP is talking about the reset, it sounds to me like he wants to use the same state for many different components, where one might not necessarily need the same state, so it might be he is just looking on how to structure his different states / different components?

Comment: Whatever the question is, it is a good practice to have resilient components that are not crashing :)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code like below:

```
function myComponent(props) => {
const {fields} = props;
return (fields && fields.someMappingOperation());
}
```

This will not throw any error and is a safe check

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use conditions or reset your state, your reducer can update it and serve it to your component. You can call an action in `componentDidMount()` and override the previous values so they will be available in your component. I assume this should be implied for each of your component since you are using a different field values for each.